# Why does creating a Docker network randomly breaks all connections from my Jenkins server?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose

I am using Jenkins to spin a docker-compose project on another server and run tests.
The server where Docker is installed is not on the same sub-network as the Jenkins server. We use a different server because the latter is provided by a third party without the ability to spin containers.

The Docker server is a Red Hat 7.7 and it's running Docker CE 19.03.1.

Jenkins connects to the Docker server in ssh, then runs a docker-compose command. Docker creates three containers and a default network for the project.

Everything works as expected, but once in while, Jenkins loses all connectivity to the Docker server. After spinning up the containers, the current job stalls until it times out, usually with a "broken pipe" error.
From then on, Jenkins cannot connect to the Docker server at all. All connections on any port simply time out.
Until I connect to it from my PC, which I for some reason still can, and manually stop and remove the containers and *the network*. Then everything works again.

The issue really seems to be that Docker network. But why would it only break connections from the Jenkins server and not my PC? And why randomly?

I am aware this may be too vague or too specific for SO. I am not even sure where to start debugging. Please let me know in the comments what information I should add, or if I should ask another community.

Comment: I had something similar happening to me but I was on a PPC using a wonky docker provided by the linux distribution. To solve this, I stopped the dockerd, removed it and manually removed all the docker related stuff. After reinstalling the official image, no more issues. It's anecdotal but I hope it helps...

Comment: On several occasions I've had issues where `docker` created a network with the same CIDR block that I use for internal instances resulting in the traffic originating from the host to be routed to the `docker` network rather than through the gateway and to the hosts I was actually trying to reach - very possible that you're encountering this as well given your description of the issue - I ended up setting the CIDR block statically for the `docker` network to avoid another randomly assigned CIDR block to conflict with my routing.

Comment: @Stefano thanks, I added OS and Docker versions in case it could be relevant.

Comment: @masseyb yes, that really sounds like it could be it. I'll try inspecting the network next time that happens. Do you remember which configuration you changed?

Comment: You can create the network with a specific subnet / gateway etc. i.e.: `docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 br0` - full details are available in the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/). Maps to the `docker-compose` "ipam" [config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). Was when I looked at my `route`'s that I was like "oh ffs".

Comment: @masseyb it totally was that. Docker was creating a default network with the same subnet address as the Jenkins server once in every few builds. I added a manual configuration with the offending address, than with another, just to be sure. Thanks a lot ❤ You can put that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker` is subject to create networks that conflict with your existing networks. For example:
[image]

Traffic from `10.0.0.0/16` to `10.1.0.0/16` and back is routed over the peering connection (default gateway).

If `docker` running on the instance in 
 the `10.0.0.0/16` subnet creates a bridged network (i.e. `br0`) with the CIDR `10.1.0.0` then you'll also get a local route for that traffic.

Trying to connect from `10.0.0.0/16` to `10.1.0.0/16` will be routed to the `docker` network and not the default gateway preventing you from connecting to your instance(s) in the `10.1.0.0/16` subnet.

You can create the [`docker` network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) with a fixed subnet / gateway to avoid these issues i.e.: `docker network create --subnet=172.128.28.0/24 br0`.

Comment: What if you need to run multiple projects, or multiple instances of the same project? Docker-compose won't start if the subnets overlap. Isn't there a way of preventing conflicts without specifying a subnet?

Comment: You could configure the [default address pool](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/8663), make sure your non-docker subnets are not in the default pools used by docker, or possibly use docker-compose overrides for your project with different [ipam configs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ipam).

Comment: Isn't really the problem reported by OP, not talking about multiple different jenkins projects running on a same instance...

Comment: Multiple overrides does not allow you to run multiple instances of the same compose project.
Just found-out about default address pool config [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4336#issuecomment-457326123). I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @vctls why not? If the only thing you're overriding is the `ipam` config, yes, you can run multiple instances of the same project from the same `docker-compose.yml` just overriding the subnet in which the project is running each time..

Comment: How do you override the subnet conf without changing the compose files? For example, to run concurrent builds.

Comment: Ok, would need to set the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` for each instance of the project but [this works fine](https://github.com/masseybradley/docker-ipam-overrides).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230020/discussion-between-vctls-and-masseyb).